# mvvm update listview when repository.save is called from a different window

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, mvvm

I have a WPF listview containing ingredients bound to viewmodel.Ingredients(MVVM pattern)

Now i want this listview to update when i add and save an ingredient in the database in a different window(calls repository.Save()).

(viewmodel.Ingredients calls repository.findAll())

I see 2 possible ways of doing this:

1) Using MVVM : Raise the property change event in Repository.Save(). But then i need to register the repository as a 2nd datasource on my view or do something else that will cause my view to update. How do i implement this?

2) An alternative would be using the MVC pattern for updates from the repository(together with the mmvm)
the viewmodel could then implement the IUpdateIngredients interface

```
public interface IUpdateIngredients
    void Update()
```

then my repository has the methods:

```
public void removeHandler(IUpdateIngredients handler)
public void AddHandler(IUpdateIngredients handler)
public void RaiseUpdateEvent() // call Update() on all the handlers
```

The viewmodel registers itself with the addHandler method. The repository.Save method calls RaiseUpdateEvent();

This would do the job, but i really want to get rid of the removehandler method. Is there a way the .NET framework can do the removing for me, perhaps using events? I want to get rid of the removeHander method because i reuse this listview on many different places, sometimes in popup widows, and i want to make sure i dont forget the call the removehandler method somewhere.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: 3. (Using MVVM) Pass common message bus to two view models. When the update occurs, publish an event which the other view model will handle. Decoupled and easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, I used a Mediator in the class that was doing the database updates, to send the message to other ViewModels to refresh their collections.

As mediator stores the target ViewModels as WeakReferences , there’s no need for removing the event handlers. Here’s a great [article](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/a-mediator-prototype-for-wpf-apps/) with sample code about the Mediator pattern by Josh Smith …

I modified the code from the above article to my needs, most importantly Mediator was implemented as a Singleton, like this.

```
private static readonly Lazy<Mediator> _lazy = new Lazy<Mediator>(() => new Mediator());
public static Mediator Instance { get { return _lazy.Value; } }
```

Now every ViewModel and broadcaster get the instance of Mediator …

```
public Mediator Mediator
        {
            get { return Mediator.Instance; }
        }
```

And the class that updates the database sends the message to ViewModel that needs to refresh.

```
Mediator.NotifyColleagues(MediatorMessages.DBUpdated);
```

ViewModel registers for messages in the constructor and then updates the collection.

```
Mediator.Register(MediatorMessages.DBUpdated, new Action(RefreshCollection));
```